# Show the best sellers and the most visited products - Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft-features

I´m working on a new online shop and want to show the best sellers and the most viewed products.

Is this possible to do with craft commerce? I guess so, since it´s a basic functionality, but I could not find how to do this in the docs.

thanks.
Sebastián.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality does not currently exist natively in Commerce (June 2016).

You could probably use a plugin like entry count (https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count) to achieve the most viewed (you might need to add commerce products support to that?).

For the best sellers, your best bet at the moment is probably to make a plugin that uses a query on the `craft_commerce_lineitems` table (along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235595/find-most-frequent-value-in-sql-column)...to return a twig variable of the n most popular product objects.